# How to get "FOO=bar.cpp meld a/$FOO b/$FOO" to work the way I expect it to?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

As far as I understand, to compare the same file in separate directories I should be able to do this:

```
FOO=bar.cpp meld a/$FOO b/$FOO
```

However, it doesn't work, as if `$FOO` is an empty string. This not surprisingly works:

```
(FOO=bar.cpp && meld a/$FOO b/$FOO)
```

My question is why does the first example not work?

Comment: Are you sure `FOO=bar.cpp echo a/$FOO b/$FOO` give you `a/$FOO b/$FOO`? I think no

Comment: Oops, I had set `FOO` globally whilst experimenting - I've deleted that example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

```
FOO=bar.cpp meld a/$FOO b/$FOO
```

It's a [Simple Command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01), so `FOO=bar.cpp` isn't executed at the time `$FOO` was expanded.

In:

```
FOO=bar.cpp && meld a/$FOO b/$FOO
```

There're 2 commands:

```
FOO=bar.cpp
```

and:

```
meld a/$FOO b/$FOO
```

When parameter substitution performed in `meld a/$FOO b/$FOO`, `FOO=bar.cpp` was executed, so `FOO` was set to `bar.cpp`.

Comment: So basically a Simple Command cannot do what I hoped it could?

Comment: @KenY-N yes, `(FOO=bar.cpp; meld "a/$FOO" "b/$FOO")` is the way to go if you don't want to `FOO` retains after command finish. Note the double quotes. You can use any statement termination like `;` above instead of `&&`.